# Is there a CSS framework similar to blueprint but doesn't define the layout in the css naming?

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I want a css framework, similar to blueprint i guess but something that keeps all layout defined in the CSS, and not in the class naming convention.

example: with blueprint you have to say class="span-6 last", maybe I want to change the last column to be the first, w/o having to change 50 html pages.

Does this exist?

Comment: yes. it's called not using a CSS framework and naming your elements something semantic.

Answer (score 0):

afaik thats a must have feature of a css layout framework, so there is no way to get around that without (serious) hacks. like this one: with [compress.rb](http://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/blob/master/lib/compress.rb) you can compile your own custom blueprint framework. you just need to setup a config file that tells the compiler i would like to use my #header as .span-18 ect.